Connecting standard clock oscillator to STM32L073 - OSC_OUT pin has to be connected?
Trying to connect ASE-14.31818MHZ-LC-T standard clock oscillator to STM32L073. According to datasheet, oscillator output signal should be connected to OSC_IN pin:

Internal STM32L073 oscillator schematic:

In bypass mode the HSE oscillator is switched off and the input pin is a standard GPIO.The external clock signal has to respect the I/O characteristics.
Should I keep OSC_OUT floating?

If the datasheet does not tell something else, you can leave OSC_OUT unconnected. (floating is a different thing)

Where would you connect OSC_OUT then? It's GPIO the internal oscillator is off.

The OSC_OUT is not even reserved for crystal amplifier output when the amplifier is bypassed. It can be used as GPIO as you wish.
